# MinGW Win32 - Condition variables are not supported

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, condition-variable

I'm using Windows 7 with MSYS64 MinGW environment.

Currently trying to get Win32 native `ConditionVariables` to work on a C++ application, but no success: the related functions appear not being declared in `windows.h`, and even LD can't resolve them from `kernel32` (if ignoring implicit declarations) .

This shows that they are not present in my `windows.h`:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:121:49: error: 'InitializeConditionVariable' was not declared in this scope
     InitializeConditionVariable (&BufferNotEmpty);
                                                 ^
main.cpp:138:45: error: 'WakeAllConditionVariable' was not declared in this scope
     WakeAllConditionVariable (&BufferNotFull);
(And so on)
```

As written in [This DevCenter page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683469(v=vs.85).aspx), CondVars are supported since Windows Vista, and needs `kernel32` to work.

So this problem should be a thing of MinGW.

My GCC properties:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-6.3.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

The source is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903(v=vs.85).aspx)

Compiling with

```
g++ main.cpp -lkernel32 -lntdll
```

Comment: Do a "find-in-files" for `InitializeConditionVariable` in the same directory containing `windows.h`.  The function will probably be inside a `#if defined` block; you will probably need to `#define`  `_WIN32_WINNT` to the appropriate platform version.  The default is to not include APIs from the more recent version of Windows unless you ask for them.

Comment: This worked - `_WIN32_WINNT` was defined as `0x0503`, and the required one for `InitializeConditionVariable` (in file `Synchapi.h`) is `0x0600`, so had to redefine. Looks like my app's compilation will have to dynamically check the versions in the future.

Comment: `#define WINVER 0x0600` and `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600` worked for me too (5 years later and MinGW's default still hasn't changed from Windows XP?)